# How to declare a php variable inside the javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code is as follows :

```
$.each(resp,function(indx,obj){

var id =1;      

table += '<tr>';
table += '<td>'+parseInt(indx+1)+'</td>';          
table += '<td>'+id+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+obj.AmcMachine.work_order_no+'</td>';
table += '<td>'+obj.AmcMachine.workOrderDate +'</td>';
'<?php $id ?>';

table +='<td>'+'<?php echo $this->Html-> link("edit",array("controller"=>"AMC",
              "action"=>"details",$id),array("target"=>"_blank"))?>'+'</td>';
table += '</tr>';
});
```

I am working with cakephp. My requirement is to send the id variable to a new php function in the controller. How to get the value of id (javascript variable) to `$id`(php varible).

Comment: PHP is executed before JavaScript (because PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side). Therefor, if you wish to modify any PHP data with JavaScript, you need to use something like AJAX.

Comment: If you are using a framework like CakePHP, you are expected to meet some principles, especially basic principles like separation of concerns. It is considered bad practice to use a language to generate code for another language. For your case, your could simply generate that link inside your HTML code then select it with a javascript selector, or use a proper template engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Why the double answer? You even get an alert if you try to post twice in one question. 2. This doesn't help the fact that PHP is executed before JavaScript, so you can't modify PHP values from JavaScript (unless you are using some Ajax-like function) (seems like you might have misunderstood the Question?)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = { url: '<?= $path; ?>' };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thejsfile.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.